# How to print a 2d matrix using JS?

Tags: javascript, python, interface

I created a sudoku solver in python. I want to display it in a 9X9 grid but don't know how to do it. I think javascript can be used for this, but I don't have much idea about that language. Can someone provide me some suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: You mean you want to draw graphics on a screen? You can use a python library for that such as the built-in `tkinter` or something like `pygame`.

Comment: Hey, you can use flask, it is a Python library that allows you to host web pages and modify them with Python. You would need to learn a bit about HTML and javascript on the way.

Comment: I know Django but I don't know how to create a grid and display values in it. The python code will return a 2D matrix of digits and I want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Bro here i present a code for you in which you can display a 9*9 board in the webpage whose elements are inserted by the user itself. The code starts...

```
function InputBoard(){
   
 var Board = new Array(9);                     // Create one dimensional Array
    
    for (var i = 0; i < Board.length; i++) {         // create 2D Array using 1D
        Board[i] = []; 
    } 
    
    var index = 0; 
    var s =prompt("Enter Elements"); 
      
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {                // Initialize 2D array elements
            Board[i][j] = s[index++]; 
        } 
    } 
      
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) { 
            document.write(Board[i][j] + " ");       // Display 2D Array
        } 
        document.write("<br>"); 
    } 
    return Board;
}
InputBoard();
```